# How to calculate numbers of "uninterrupted" repeats in an array in python?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 0,1 numpy array like this:

```
 [0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0]
```

I want to have a function that tells me number `1` is repeated `3,2,4` times in this array, respectively. Is there a simple numpy function for this?

Comment: You are looking for an rle. There are plenty of implementations around.

Comment: Reopened because the duplicate is not the same question; Feel free to close with better duplicates.

Comment: Thank you @Psidom!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume you only have 0s and 1s:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0])

# pad a with 0 at both sides for edge cases when a starts or ends with 1
d = np.diff(np.pad(a, pad_width=1, mode='constant'))
# subtract indices when value changes from 0 to 1 from indices where value changes from 1 to 0
np.flatnonzero(d == -1) - np.flatnonzero(d == 1)
# array([3, 2, 4])
```

Answer (score 2):

This is one way to do it to find first the clusters and then get their frequency using `Counter`. The first part is inspired from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25664682/how-to-find-cluster-sizes-in-2d-numpy-array) answer for 2d arrays. I added the second `Counter` part to get the desired answer.

If you find the linked original answer helpful, please visit it and upvote it.

```
from scipy.ndimage import measurements
from collections import Counter

arr = np.array([0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0])

cluster, freq = measurements.label(arr)

print (list(Counter(cluster).values())[1:])
# [3, 2, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

A custom implementation?

```
def count_consecutives(predicate, iterable):
  tmp = []
  for e in iterable:
    if predicate(e): tmp.append(e)
    else:
      if len(tmp) > 0: yield(len(tmp)) # > 1 if you want at least two consecutive
      tmp = []
  if len(tmp) > 0: yield(len(tmp)) # > 1 if you want at least two consecutive
```

So you can:

```
array = [0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0]
(count_consecutives(lambda x: x == 0, array)
#=> [3, 2, 4]
```

And also:

```
array = [0,0,0,1,2,3,0,0,3,2,1,0,0,1,11,10,10,0,0,100]
count_consecutives(lambda x: x > 1, array)
# => [2, 2, 3, 1]
```