# Count consecutive equal values in array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Say I have the following `numpy` array:

```
a = np.array([1,5,5,2,3,6,5,2,5,5,5])
```

I'm trying to come up with a `numpy` solution to count the amount of times a given value appears consecutively. So, for example for number `5` I'd like to get:

```
array([2,1,3])
```

As it appears consecutively  3 times in the array, with the specified amount of repetitions on each time.

Comment: Certainly can be adapted: `[sum(1 for _ in group) for key, group in itertools.groupby(a) if key == 5]`

Comment: There's another answer with GroupBy... Like I've already said looking for a numpy one. The one I was making reference to was the other one.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, just seen the question in review and saying that other answer could be adapted (you can can construct a new array with that list), not necessarily what you wanted, but it can be done. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is one option adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54446907/how-to-calculate-numbers-of-uninterrupted-repeats-in-an-array-in-python/54447096#54447096):

```
def count_consecutive(arr, n):
    # pad a with False at both sides for edge cases when array starts or ends with n
    d = np.diff(np.concatenate(([False], arr == n, [False])).astype(int))
    # subtract indices when value changes from False to True from indices where value changes from True to False
    return np.flatnonzero(d == -1) - np.flatnonzero(d == 1)

count_consecutive(a, 5)
# array([2, 1, 3])
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are okay with `list` then groupby can be used

```
from itertools import groupby
a=[1,5,5,2,3,6,5,2,5,5,5]
[len(list(v)) for k,v in groupby(a) if k==5]
```

Output

```
[2, 1, 3]
```

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of `itertools.groupby`. Really looking for a numpy one, but thanks